# JQuery Mobile responsive grid inside cell of another responsive grid

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design, jquery-mobile-grid

I try to have a second responsive ui-grid inside a block of the first one, but I'm not able to get something like this to work. 
This would behave like a 25% 25% 50% fluid responsive layout.

Here is a short sample of what I mean:

```html
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-a">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <img src="images/jquery-logo.png" width="100%" />   
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Here is a sample of what i get now:
http://jsfiddle.net/j5zbB/

The idea shall be that: at bigger screen sizes, two form elements are positioned on the same line, and at smaller sizes, they are positioned below each other.

*UPDATE*

Please, let me better explain with pictures the idea beyond this question.

This would be the nested layout at bigger screen sizes, like in a tablet, landscape:
[image]

This would be the nested layout in a tablet, portrait:
[image]

This would be the nested layout at very small screen sizes, like in a phone:
[image]

Maybe there is another way to achieve something like that without ui-grids, or someone can help? Thanks to all in advance.